# GKE node instance reset in several zones

Tags: google-compute-engine

Using GKE on 2 region northamerica-northeast1 and us-central1, I experiment from time to time node deletion and recreation for example:
node Zone northamerica-northeast1-b Created Apr 10, 2021, 1:25:23 AM
from and instance-pool Running  northamerica-northeast1-b   1   Mar 30, 2021, 6:13:40 PM

no events nor alarms was raised, is there any way to have explanations?

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume that you don’t have Preemptible nodes. As you probably have autoscaling enable in your nodepools, the node may be removed by the autoscaler.

If you want to gather more information you can go to the Cloud Logging section  and search for the node logs, you can use a basic query:

> “gke-node-name”

Reference [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#how_cluster_autoscaler_works), [advance query](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries), [query samples](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/query-library)